# Automatically restart simple Linux daemon (polipo) when it dies

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

I have a polipo proxy running on Ubuntu. It's set to start automatically on boot, but occasionally it just dies. What's the simplest way to have it automatically restarted whenever it exits unexpectedly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `init` and `upstart` for this. For latest Ubuntu you will need to use [upstart](http://wiki.frugalware.org/index.php/Upstart_Job_HOWTO).

```
man inittab
man upstart
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding an upstart script, but after spending an hour on this it just wouldn't start. Typical Linux - nothing ever "just works". *sigh*

Comment: Can you paste your script into your question? This community is better at technical stuff...

Comment: Sorry, I've given up and deleted the script in disgust.Have a +1, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

See: [Bug #505391 in polipo (Ubuntu): “upstart config for polipo”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/polipo/+bug/505391)